# Show/disprove that a system of equations expresses all the natural numbers $\forall\mathbb{N}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I discovered the following system of equations that seem to complement each other;
I'm wondering if they are indeed equivalent to all the natural numbers $\forall\mathbb{N}$?

$$
  \begin{gather}
  D(1) = 2k + 2 \\
  D(2) = 2^2k + 1 \\
  D(3) = 2^3k + 7 \\
  D(4) = 2^4k + 3 \\
  D(5) = 2^5k + 27 \\
  D(6) = 2^6k + 11 \\
  D(7) = 2^7k + 107 \\
  D(8) = 2^8k + 43 \\
  D(9) = 2^9k + 427 \\
  \dots
  \end{gather}
$$

If we model the series as $D(n | n \in \mathbb{N}) = \{2^nk + X \mid k \ge 0\}$

The offsets $X=\{2,1,7,3,27,\dots\}$ are found from the series $2$ orders below by $4X-1$

For example $7 = (2)(4) -1$, $3 = (1)(4)-1$, $27 = (7)(4)-1$ and so on

Sketching the values seem to produce collectively all the natural numbers and without any overlaps. The diagram illustrates the first $33$ terms, showing how the series seems to complement each other

[image]

Trying to sum the series together, or by other methods, I wish to prove (or disprove) that all the numbers are in fact expressed, but not sure how to proceed. Also wondering if the system of equations are something that is recognised elsewhere.

Comment: Are you trying to show that we may find a collection $(x_n)_{n \geq 1}$ of natural numbers such that every natural number may be expressed in exactly one way as $2^n k + x_n$ for $k, n$ naturals?

Comment: It seems that what you are doing is to describe a mapping from $\Bbb N$ to the space of sequences with natural terms (denoted $\Bbb N ^{\Bbb N}$), therefore your question is clearly unclear.

Comment: @Patrick's implementation looks sensible to me.

Comment: I like the explorative feel (+1)

Comment: By the way, the sequences of the offsets $x_n$ are claimed to be: $x_{2n} = \frac{1}{6} (2+2^{2n})$ and $x_{2n+1} = \frac{1}{6}(2+5 \times 2^{2n+1})$.

Comment: Indeed this enumerates exactly the positive integers, that is, each positive integer appears once. To show this, first note that the odd-numbered D-sequences are made of the integers $$O_{n,k}=\frac{1+2^{2k+1}(6n+1)}3\qquad k\geqslant0\ n\geqslant0$$ and the even-numbered D-sequences are made of the integers $$E_{n,k}=\frac{1+2^{2k}(6n+5)}3\qquad k\geqslant0\ n\geqslant0$$ Next, note that $O_{0,0}=1$ and start from some $i\geqslant2$. If the dyadic valuation of $3i-1$ is odd, then $3i-1=2^{2k+1}(1+2j)$ for some nonnegative $(k,j)$ and the proof that $i=O_{n,k}$ for some $n$ is complete if ...

Comment: .. one can show that $1+2j=1$ mod $6$, or, equivalently, that $j=0$ mod $3$. Likewise, if the dyadic valuation of $3i-1$ is even, then $3i-1=2^{2k}(1+2j)$ for some nonnegative $(k,j)$ and the proof that $i=E_{n,k}$ for some $n$ is complete if one can show that $1+2j=5$ modulo $6$, or, equivalently, that $j=2$ mod $3$. Can you show these two factoids, thus ending the proof? ((And no, there is no connection to Collatz, sorry.))

Answer (score 1):

This is rather a hint than an answer...

\begin{gather}
D(1) = 2k + 2   & \text{ all even numbers} \\
 \text{ now all odd numbers}\\
D(2) = 2^2k + 1 & \text{all odd numbers =1 modulo 4}\\
 \text{ now all odd numbers =3 modulo 4 remain and have to be listed} \\
 \text{this are that =3 modulo 8  and that =7 modulo 8 } \\
 \text{ first that of =7 modulo 8} \\
D(3) = 2^3k + 7\\
 \text{ now remaining =3 and = 11 modulo 16} \\
D(4) = 2^4k + 3 & \text{ and so on} \\
\dots
\end{gather}

I think you can decode this/formalize this now yourself... What you need is a formalization for the residues which satisfy that in each step 2 exclusive classes of numbers remain. [I've seen this in the context of the Collatz-problem 2.3,pg 6-7](http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/Collatz061102.pdf) where there are two sequences of residues $1,5,21,85,...$ and $3,13,53,213,...$ which provide a similar classification of the natural numbers.
(For instance I've seen, that your residues follow two interwoven sequences with the rule $a_{k+1}=4a_k-1$)

Comment: do you think this is accurate? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739001/functions-of-n-odd-subset-mathbbn-in-the-collatz-series